# Production build issue (img tag error) in Angular V5 Webpack tutorial

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

Running the tutorial: https://v5.angular.io/guide/webpack

Dev build successfully renders the image. 
[dev build view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLd66.png)

Production Build does not correctly transpose the image resource and the image tag. There are some weird artefacts present:
[production build view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLVbx.png)

**HTML file:**

```
<main>
  <h1>Hello from Angular App with Webpack</h1>

  <img src="../assets/images/angular.png">
</main>
```

**webpack.common.js:**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/main.ts'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: [
          {
            loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
            options: { configFileName: helpers.root('src', 'tsconfig.json') }
          } , 'angular2-template-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallbackLoader: 'style-loader', loader: 'css-loader?sourceMap' })
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: 'raw-loader'
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    // Workaround for angular/angular#11580
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
      /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
      helpers.root('./src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),

    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

**webpack.dev.js:**

```
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

  output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
  ],

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    stats: 'minimal'
  }
});
```

Webpack.prod.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'production';

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
  devtool: 'source-map',

  output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10618
      minimize: true,
      mangle: {
        keep_fnames: true
      }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[hash].css'),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV)
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      htmlLoader: {
        minimize: false // workaround for ng2
      }
    })
  ]
});
```

Unsure of what could be causing this. I believe that it is a file-loader or minify error.

For reference, the output, **app.js**

```
/***/ 363:
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

eval("module.exports = __webpack_require__.p + \"assets/angular.9db278d630f5fabd8e7ba16c2e329a3a.png\";//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJmaWxlIjoiMzYzLmpzIiwic291cmNlcyI6WyJ3ZWJwYWNrOi8vLy4vc3JjL2Fzc2V0cy9pbWFnZXMvYW5ndWxhci5wbmc/NjA4NyJdLCJzb3VyY2VzQ29udGVudCI6WyJtb2R1bGUuZXhwb3J0cyA9IF9fd2VicGFja19wdWJsaWNfcGF0aF9fICsgXCJhc3NldHMvYW5ndWxhci45ZGIyNzhkNjMwZjVmYWJkOGU3YmExNmMyZTMyOWEzYS5wbmdcIjtcblxuXG4vLy8vLy8vLy8vLy8vLy8vLy9cbi8vIFdFQlBBQ0sgRk9PVEVSXG4vLyAuL3NyYy9hc3NldHMvaW1hZ2VzL2FuZ3VsYXIucG5nXG4vLyBtb2R1bGUgaWQgPSAzNjNcbi8vIG1vZHVsZSBjaHVua3MgPSAxIl0sIm1hcHBpbmdzIjoiQUFBQSIsInNvdXJjZVJvb3QiOiIifQ==");

/***/ }),

/***/ 364:
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

eval("module.exports = \"<main>\\n  <h1>Hello from Angular App with Webpack</h1>\\n\\n  <img src=\\\"\" + __webpack_require__(363) + \"\\\">\\n</main>\\n\";//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,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");

/***/ }),
```

It is deployed and hosted on a firebase instance from the `Dist` folder.

Comment: Is it just me or are you not closing your img tag ? <img src="..." />

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the answer is due to this bug:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10618

Setting mangle to false corrected the problem.

```
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10618
      minimize: true,
      mangle: false
      // {
      //   keep_fnames: true
      // }
    }),
```